# c# graphics.drawstring for chinese characters come out wrong

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to print chinese characters using drawstring and all chinese characters come out bold.  i already installed chinese fonts on the machine and specified font style to regular.  What am i doing wrong?

```
void Print_Receipt(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) 
{ 
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    float fontheight = font.GetHeight(); 
    int x = 10; 
    int y = 10; 
    int offset = 40; 
    SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.Black); 
    g.DrawString("測試消息",
        new Font("Courier New", 10, FontStyle.Regular), sb, x, y);
}
```

Comment: Try using a different typeface. Courier New (on my computer at least) does not contain Chinese characters.

Comment: But they do come out as Chinese characters? I find the difference between Bold and Standard in courier New rather small, btw. Also: did you mean to include a Code Snippet? and: If it is winforms, please add the Tag for it!

Comment: Also, you're creating two `Font` instances and only using the second, and you're leaking handles because you're not disposing of both `Font` objects nor the `SolidBrush` instance.

Comment: i tried different fonts and it does come out correct.  it's just all bold.

Comment: can't repro unless set `FontStyle.Bold`.